# Does not contain 4 grade - Java

Tags: java

```
public class Degree {

public Degree(List<Grade> year2, List<Grade> year3) {

    if (year2.size() != 4 || year3.size() != 4) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }   
}
```

i have statement for "does not contain 4 grade" to create Junit test. is there a better way to improve this statement (for my knowledge to help me out in future).

```
  @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
  public void donotcontaingrade() {
    List<Grade> year2 = new ArrayList<>();
    year2.add(new Grade(1));
    year2.add(new Grade(2));
    year2.add(new Grade(3));

    List<Grade> year3 = new ArrayList<>();
    year3.add(new Grade(1));
    year3.add(new Grade(2));
    year3.add(new Grade(3));
    new Degree(year2, year3);
}
```

Example of my Junit test

Comment: `< 4`. Your test would pass `5`, and `5` contains a `4`.

Comment: if i change to == 3, would it make difference?

Comment: Your test would still pass but only if one or both arrays has exactly three elements instead of "not 4" in other words it narrows the scope of the test.

Comment: is there any other way to write that if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test would pass, in that the exception would be thrown.

However, you made a common mistake of trying to test multiple issues in one test. You really need four tests for full coverage.

1. The Happy Path, where your pass in two valid arguments and get back an instance, not an exception.
2. You pass a bad value and a good value, and get an exception.
3. You pass a good value and a bad value, and get an exception.
4. You pass in two bad values and get an exception.

Late addition: When an if statement contains an OR operator, then you can't get 100% coverage in tools. That's because the coverage tool wants to check both conditions false. However, the OR stops checking on the first false, so the second condition is not checked.

To 100% coverage, split the if with OR into two if. The code execution is the same, but the coverage tool will see all code exercised.

Comment: What is the First one? not sure about that and im getting 3/4 branch coverage with that junit test

Comment: The happy path means that everything went smoothly. Now that you mention it, you can't get 100% coverage with in OR condition. That's because the second condition won't be evaluated if the first one is false. So, test 4. won't "get credit" from you coverage tool. When I really want 100% coverage, I break the IF with an OR into two IF.

Comment: if (year2.size() == 3)  {
   if (year3.size() == 3) {// does not contain 4 grade
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
   }
  }

Comment: if i change my if statement like this, with those test you recommend would it pass 4/4 coverage?